Isoelastic utility functions, how to calculate risk boundaries.
I am trying to replicate a calculation I found in a paper that calculates the level of risk aversion for an individual to choose one option over the other, but I am struggling to solve it. Ideally, looking for a value for $\theta$ would mean that an individual would choose option A over option B. This is in an instance where option A an individual receives 18 tokens for certain or enters a lottery to earn either 12 or 25 where the probability of either outcome is 50%.
$$
U(A)>E[U(B)]
$$
$$
U(18)>Pr(12)U(12)+Pr(25)U(25)
$$
$$
\frac{{18}^{1-\theta}-1}{1-\theta}>0.5\left[\frac{{12}^{1-\theta}-1}{1-\theta}\right]+0.5\left[\frac{{25}^{1-\theta}-1}{1-\theta}\right]
$$

I don't think this function has a nice closed-form solution (other than $\theta = 1$ which is trivial), but you can solve it by numerical methods. The easiest one would be graphing from which you could approximate if $0 < \theta < 0.4243$, option $B$ is better, and if $0.4244 < \theta < 1$, option $A$ is better.

What paper is it?
